# PowerShell find next empty column in Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I need a PowerShell snippet that searches for the next empty column in an Excel sheet.

Every help is appreciated.

I've tried this so far:

```
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $True
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Garry\Desktop\test.xlsx")
    $Sheet = $Excel.WorkSheets.Item(1)
$xlLastCell = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Constants]::xlLastColumn
$z=1
Do{$z, $z++}until ($Sheet.Column.Item(1, $xlLastCell).Value -eq "")
```

I tried to loop it so it checks every column if there is a value with the do and until statement, but I always get the error 
*"It is not possible to call a method for an expression that has the value NULL."* The errorstatement refers to the Do until loop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [tour], [ask] and offer a [mcve] of what you tried so far.
We are not a coding service ;)

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code and relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: In addition the code, further explanation is required... (see the links provided)

Comment: @ashleedawg I have edited my post, hopefully it's now understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change condition from "0" to "$null" and replace $xlLastCell with counter $z:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $true

$workBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Garry\Desktop\test.xlsx")
$workSheet = $excel.WorkSheets.Item(1)
# not needed $xlLastCell = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Constants]::xlLastColumn
$z = 1
Do {
    $z
}
until ( $workSheet.Cells.Item(1, $z++).Value2 -eq $null )
```